# Mean of few months for a monthly data in r

Tags: r, mean

I want to find the average of the months from Nov to March, say Nov 1982 to Mar 1983. Then, for my result, I want a column with year and mean in another. If the mean is taken till Mar 1983, I want the year to be shown as 1983 along with that mean.
[This is how my data looks like.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jnwCi.png)

I want my result to look like this.

```
1983 29.108
1984 26.012
```

I am not very good with R packages, If there is an easy way to do this. I would really appreciate any help. Thank you.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). Images are not the right way to share data/code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one approach to get average of Nov-March every year.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  #Remove data for month April-October
  filter(!between(month, 4, 10)) %>%
  #arrange the data by year and month
  arrange(year, month) %>%
  #Remove 1st 3 months of the first year and 
  #last 2 months of last year
  filter(!(year == min(year) & month %in% 1:3 | 
         year == max(year) & month %in% 11:12)) %>%
  #Create a group column for every November entry
  group_by(grp = cumsum(month == 11)) %>%
  #Take average for each year 
  summarise(year = last(year),
            value = mean(value)) %>%
  select(-grp)

# A tibble: 2 x 2
#   year  value
#  <int>  <dbl>
#1  1982  0.308
#2  1983 -0.646
```

**data**

It is easier to help if you provide data in a reproducible format which can be copied easily.

```
set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(year = rep(1981:1983, each = 12),month = 1:12,value = rnorm(36))
```

Comment: Thank you. I will keep in mind about reproducible data format next time.

Answer (score 2):

With dplyr

```
# remove the "#" before in the begining of the next line if dplyr or tidyverse is not installed
#install.packages("dplyr") 

library(dplyr) #reading the library

colnames(df) <- c("year","month","value") #here I assumed your dataset is named df


df<- df%>%
  group_by(year) %>%
  summarize(av_value =mean(value))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this as follow using `tidyverse`

```
require(tidyverse)

year <- rep(1982:1984, 3)
month <- rep(1:12, 3)
value <- runif(length(month))

dat <- data.frame(year, month, value)

head(dat)
```

`dat` looks like your data

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
   year value
  <int> <dbl>
1  1982 0.450
2  1983 0.574
3  1984 0.398
```

The trick then is to `group_by` and `summarise`

```
dat %>% 
  group_by(year) %>% 
  summarise(value = mean(value))
```

Which gives you

```
# A tibble: 3 × 2
   year value
  <int> <dbl>
1  1982 0.450
2  1983 0.574
3  1984 0.398
```